# Get values of dropped items in sortable comuns from code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have implemented drag and drop jquery on my web page and its been working fine. I am loading the columns from the code behind as per user selection and user can edit those as per their needs. But when i am trying to get the items selected in the destination column, its repeater.items count is zero and source repeater.items count as same as it was on page load. Here is the code .

```
<div class="Content" id="DragAndDrop" style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center; font-size: 9px;">
                    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable" style="width: 45%; border: groove">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="DivisionSource" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--<li class="ui-state-default" id="lblSource" ><%# Eval("DivisionName") %></li>--%>
                                <li class="ui-state-default" >
                                     <asp:Label id="lblSource" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DivisionName") %>' ></asp:Label> </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable" style="width: 45%; border: groove; list-style: none">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="DivisionDest" runat="server" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <li class="ui-state-default" >
                                     <asp:Label id="lblDest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DivisionName") %>' ></asp:Label> </li>
                               <%-- <li class="ui-state-default" id="<%# Eval("DivisionID") %>" style="display: none;">SAP: Strategizing Activities and Practices</li>--%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Data are bounded by repeter databound on pageload()

```
DivisionSource.DataSource = DivResultSource
                DivisionSource.DataBind()

                DivisionDest.DataSource = DivResultDest
                DivisionDest.DataBind()
```

Code behind to access the data:

```
Dim DivisionSource As Repeater = Wizard1.FindControl("DivisionSource")
Dim DivisionDest As Repeater = Wizard1.FindControl("DivisionDest")    
Dim SelectedDivisionvalue As String = Nothing
                                Dim i As Integer = 1
                                For Each item As RepeaterItem In DivisionDest.Items
                                    If (item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then


                                        Dim lblValue As Label = CType(item.FindControl("lblDest"), Label)
                                        SelectedDivisionvalue = lblValue.Text 
                                        i += 1
                                    End If
                                Next
```

On postback, DivisionSource.items count are same as default when the page loaded and DivisionDest.items count is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i end up doing is i was able to get the order of the both source and destination repeter from the javascrip function. I saved the value of the order in hidden variable and passed that to the code behind. Here is how i was able to get the order.

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  receive: function (event, ui) {
       // alert('Receive!');

       var $self = $(this);
       var $item = ui.item;
       var $sender = ui.sender;
        if ($(event.target).attr("id") == "sortable2") {

            var order1 = $sender.sortable('toArray').toString();
            var order2 = $self.sortable('toArray').toString();

           //alert("Order 1:" + order1 + "\n Order 2:" + order2);
            }
         },
}).disableSelection();
```

This

```
var order2 = $self.sortable('toArray')
```

will give you order in ***arrayList*** and you can do ***.lenght*** and other function to calcaulate no of items if you wan to restrict user to a limit.

Answer (score 1):

You try add server side controls with drag and drop in client side. Server controls are rendered on the server side and you can't do it with your way. So controls add to repeater in your browser (client side) but they are unavailable  when page post backed an `DivisionSource.items` count are same as default.

> If you want to do it, you can use `hidden field` or `session`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please see my answer how i did it. Your answer guided in correct direction.